# What does $\|u\|_{L^p(B(x,r))}$ mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, lp-spaces

I saw $\|u\|_{L^1(B(x,r))}$ in my text. But I don't know what it means. 
I know what $L^p$ norm is, but with the ball, I am not sure.  Does it mean the volume inside $L^p$ norm$=r$? There isn't integral sign though.

This is the text:

**THEOREM 7** (Estimates on derivatives). Assume $u$ is harmonic in $U$. Then 
$$ \tag{18} |D^\alpha u(x_0)| \le \frac{C_k}{r^{n+k}} \| u\|_{L^1(B(x_0, r))}.$$

Comment: What text is that from?

Answer (score 1):

> *Definition:*  Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space.  Then $L^p(X)$ is defined to be
>   $$ \left\{ f : X \to \mathbb{C} \ \middle|\ \|f\|_{L^p(X)} < \infty \right\}, $$
>   where
>   $$ \|f\|_{L^p(X)} := \left( \int_{X} |f|^p \,\mathrm{d}\mu \right)^{1/p}. $$

In your example, $B(x_0,r)$ is a measure space, with the measure $\mu$ being the restriction of the ambient measure to the $r$-ball (presumably, Lebesgue measure coming from $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$, though it is hard to say from the small excerpt you provide—it doesn't really do any harm to ignore the measure theory here and regard the integrals as Riemann integrals).  Hence
$$ \| u \|_{L^1(B(x_0,r))} := \int_{B(x_0,r)} |u(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very helpful.

Comment: @zhongyuanchen Again, I am curious as to what text it is that you are reading.  It looks to me, based on this question and another that you posted, that you are reading Evan's book on PDE.  If so, this notation is explained fairly well in one of the appendices (if I recall correctly, appendix B on function spaces).

Answer (score 0):

It is the $\mathbf{L}^1$ norm of the restriction of $u$ to $B(x_0,r)$.